# How do I use vue from coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript code:

```
app = new Vue el='#app',
  data =
    message: "Hello, World!"
```

Which has compiled to the following javascript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 2.3.2
var app, data, el;

app = new Vue(el = '#app', data = {
  message: "Hello, World!"
});

//# sourceMappingURL=aesthetics.js.map
```

And I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
{{ message }}
</div>
<!-- Load JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/aesthetics.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(Aesthetics.js is the link to my compiled, javascript, code). 
When I run my app it does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any error messages when using the browser development tools (F12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Vue` takes an options object, not a series of parameters. Try (in coffeescript)

```
new Vue(
  app: '#app'
  data: message: 'Hello world')
```